# NLP extracting associate word

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I'm new to the NLP algorithm. I'm working wit python 3 in french.
I would like to extract a group of word  from a text that belong together. For example "left foot" "bottle of water". 
how can i found a rule that will extract a group of word from a text/sentence.

(ps: I'm french, sorry if i don't express myself well)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad and vague, please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you post an example of the input and desired output, it will increase your chances of getting a response

Comment: i'm sorry that it wasn't clear. I'm trying to extract terms from several document. it's complicate to explain it in english.                                                 For example from this text on wikipedia :" Huntington's disease , also known as Huntington's chorea, is an inherited disorder that results in death of brain cells.The earliest symptoms are often subtle problems with mental abilities". i'm trying to extract terms as "hungtinton's disease" or " subtle problems with mental abilities"  for example. How can i associate words from a text that have a certain sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gensim [***Phrase (collocation) detection***](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) to find common phrases in your sentences (2 word phrases or 3 word phrases), example:

```
bigram = Phraser(phrases)
sent = [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new', u'york', u'was', u'there']
print(bigram[sent])
Output: [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new_york', u'was', u'there']
```

keep your attention on the word new york.

to find if 2 words is similar you can calculate word vectors for them and calculate cosine similarity, check [***Gensim***](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) documentation

Pre-trained word vectors for French look [***on this repository***](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors)

Good luck)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. i will try that !

Comment: i have another question, how do you do if you want to extract "the mayor of new york"